# Linux not finding Serial Ports

Tags: debian, serial-port

I have debian6.0 installed on my machine. It has four comports of which 2 cannot be found. From looking that the systems bios I can see that the ports address are:

```
PORT      ADDRESS      IRQ
1         3F8          4
2         2F8          3
3         3E8          10
4         2E8          11
```

Ports 1 and 2 are found by debian but 3 and 4 are not. From what I understand I can setup the ports with this information using `setserial`. I tried:

```
setserial /dev/ttyS2 port 0x03e8 irq 10 baud_base 115200
```

but I recieve:

```
/dev/ttyS2: No such file or directory
```

Is it safe to create a file in `/dev` named `ttyS2`? and try to run the same command again?

**edit:**

As per jordanm's request:

```
# cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  2 pty
  3 ttyp
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
 29 fb
128 ptm
136 pts
180 usb
189 usb_device
253 rtc
254 hidraw

Block devices:
259 blkext
  7 loop
  8 sd
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
```

**EDIT:**

so I made the device file with:

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS2 c 4 66
```

Than I tried to setup the com-port with:

```
setserial /dev/ttyS2 port 0x03e8 irq 10 autoconfig
```

but recieved:

```
/dev/ttyS2: No such device or address
```

There is in fact hardware for two additional serial ports.

Comment: `dev` files must be made with `mknod`. Show the output of `cat /proc/devices`

Comment: @jordanm I updated question with requested information

Comment: it's `Baud rate`, not `Boud rate`.

Comment: @BatchyX I know but thats how it is spelled in the bios.... :S

Comment: If the BIOS's ACPI tables are as botched as their spelling, i would suggest updating it.

Comment: Anything in the kernel syslog after you run the `setserial`?

Comment: Are all of the 4 com ports on the mainboard or are 3 and 4 on an adapter? Can you add the output (after a reboot) of `dmesg | grep 16550`?

Comment: @Richard : Can you please paste your kernel arguments?

Answer (score 3):

in the grub bootloader I have parameter `8250.nr_uarts = 4` to the boot line. After that, I was able to set up serial ports using `setserial`

https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-15.html#ss15.3

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced a similar problem with undefined UART serial ports and Linux, with an ARCHMI PC. dmesg | grep serial was not showing any results. After many trials, I noticed that it was a BIOS problem. After disabling the "Quick Boot" option, everything run smoothly and serial ports were loaded correctly with UART, dmesg showed results. Just in case it helps by chance.